# How come slicing a pandas series returns a different output when using `.loc[]` vs. just `[]`?

Tags: pandas, series

My apologies if this question has been asked elsewhere; I couldn't find an answer.

I have a pandas *series* (that is, ***not*** a *DataFrame*) and I want to get the first *n* values.

1. Define the series

   ```py
   import numpy as np
   import pandas as pd

   my_s = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c', np.nan, 'f', 'l', 'd', 'a', 'a', np.nan])
   my_s

   #> 0      a
   #> 1      b
   #> 2      c
   #> 3    NaN
   #> 4      f
   #> 5      l
   #> 6      d
   #> 7      a
   #> 8      a
   #> 9    NaN
   #> dtype: object
   ```
2. Set *n*

   ```py
   n = 5
   ```
3. Slice

   3.1 With `[:n]`

   ```py
   my_s[:n]
   #> 0      a
   #> 1      b
   #> 2      c
   #> 3    NaN
   #> 4      f
   #> dtype: object
   ```

   3.2 With `.loc[:n]`

   ```py
   my_s.loc[:n]
   #> 0      a
   #> 1      b
   #> 2      c
   #> 3    NaN
   #> 4      f
   #> 5      l <~~~~~~~~~ this one is included here but wasn't above
   #> dtype: object
   ```

How come *3.1* and *3.2* return different results? I googled it but could not find any relevant discussion of this.

Answer (score 0):

need different example for explain

**Example**

```
s1 = pd.Series([a, b, c,  d, e], index=list('ABCDE'))
```

s1

```
A    a
B    b
C    c
D    d
E    e
dtype: int64
```

[ ] is location slicing on series:

```
s1[:3]

A    a
B    b
C    c
dtype: int64
```

loc is label slicing:

```
s1.loc[:'D']

A    a
B    b
C    c
D    d
dtype: int64
```

location slicing does not include right border

```
s1[3]
output: d
```

s1[:3] does not include d

Comment: Thanks. I kinda understand but not fully. In my example, `my_s[:n]` is slicing based on what? I don't have numbers in the values. I have letters.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding so I re-edited my answer for you. You need to know what `location` of index is. value doesn't matter